# "before each" hook for "Fetching contract address" for forked mainnet in hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, mainnet

I have forked ethereum mainnet and I have a contract for which I want to run tests in forked network. Below are my code:

`test.js`:

```
const {
  time,
  loadFixture,
} = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
const { anyValue } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/withArgs");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { isCallTrace } = require("hardhat/internal/hardhat-network/stack-traces/message-trace");

describe("Testing MySwap Contract",()=>{
  let mySimpleFlashLoanV3Factory, mySimpleFlashLoanV3;
  beforeEach(async() =>{
    const aaveMainnetPoolAddressProvider = '0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5';
// const aaveGoreliFaucet = '0x1ca525Cd5Cb77DB5Fa9cBbA02A0824e283469DBe';
    mySimpleFlashLoanV3Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MySimpleFlashLoanV3");
    mySimpleFlashLoanV3 = await mySimpleFlashLoanV3Factory.deploy(aaveMainnetPoolAddressProvider);
    // mySimpleFlashLoanV3 = await mySimpleFlashLoanV3.deployed();
    console.log("deployed----");
  })
  it("Fetching contract address",async () =>{
    console.log("address: ");
  })
})
```

and this is my `MyFlashLoan` code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.10;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


import {
  IPoolAddressesProvider
} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import { IPool } from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol";
import { IFlashLoanSimpleReceiver } from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/flashloan/interfaces/IFlashLoanSimpleReceiver.sol";
import { IERC20 } from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";
import { SafeMath } from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/SafeMath.sol";

// interface IFaucet {
//     function mint(
//         address _token,
//         uint256 _amount
//     ) external;
// }

abstract contract FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase is IFlashLoanSimpleReceiver {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  IPoolAddressesProvider public immutable override ADDRESSES_PROVIDER;
  IPool public immutable override POOL;
//   IFaucet public immutable FAUCET;

//   constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider provider, IFaucet faucet) {
//     ADDRESSES_PROVIDER = provider;
//     POOL = IPool(provider.getPool());
//     FAUCET = faucet;
//   }

  constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider provider) {
    ADDRESSES_PROVIDER = provider;
    POOL = IPool(provider.getPool());
  }
}


/** 
    !!!
    Never keep funds permanently on your FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase contract as they could be 
    exposed to a 'griefing' attack, where the stored funds are used by an attacker.
    !!!
 */
contract MySimpleFlashLoanV3 is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    IERC20 sellToken;
    IERC20 buyToken;
    address spender;
    address payable swapTarget;
    bytes swapCallData;

    constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider) FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(_addressProvider) {}

    function fillQuote(
    )
        internal // Must attach ETH equal to the `value` field from the API response.
    {
        // some code
    }
    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    )
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
// some code
    }

    function executeFlashLoan(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        IERC20 _sellToken,
        // The `buyTokenAddress` field from the API response.
        IERC20 _buyToken,
        // The `allowanceTarget` field from the API response.
        address allowanceTarget,
        // The `to` field from the API response.
        address payable _to,
        // The `data` field from the API response.
        bytes calldata _data
    ) public {
 // some code
    }
}
```

I am new to blockchain development and using hardhat for contract development. I have forked the ethereum mainnet using it. May anyone tell me what's I am doing wrong which is giving me this huge error:

```
Testing MySwap Contract
    1) "before each" hook for "Fetching contract address"


  0 passing (8s)
  1 failing

  1) Testing MySwap Contract
       "before each" hook for "Fetching contract address":
     Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted without a reason string", method="estimateGas",....
```

Answer (score 0):

The contract at the address you linked does not implement the `getPool` function you are trying to call in the constructor (see [contract on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5#readContract)).

For the future, I can recommend using [`hardhat's console.log`](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network) in your tests to determine which line in your code is failing.